# Js object assign into subfield of another object

Tags: javascript

given

```
let o1 = {
  meta: {
    intent: 'i'
  }
};
const t1 = {
  topic: 't'
};
```

I want to generate an object

```
{
    meta: {
        intent: 'i',
        topic: 't',
    },
}
```

How can I do this in Object.assign or other ways please ?

Comment: `Object.assign(o1.meta, t1)`?

Comment: @Phil, sorry typo, edited the original question

Comment: @zerkms, works, thanks a lot ! Initially I did assign the result to another obj, that didn't work.